# How to profile "native code" in android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, profiling

I am using AndroidStudio 1.2

I tried to profile native code in android with reference to [SOLUTION](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/android-platform/12TmvIr6RNM/L2MrUpNbEIwJ)
in this link where I tried to figure out the usage of aprof even though I make the required tweaks -> giving permission to write,Adding config in android.mk as in the solution the file is not getting dumped in /mnt/sdcard below is my code..

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".DisplayMemory"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_display_memory" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".DisplayCpu"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_display_cpu" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".BatteryInfo"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_battery_info" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".TrafficAnalysis"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_traffic_analysis" >
    </activity>
</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Android.mk

```
LOCAL_ENABLE_APROF := true
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := CalcNative.c
LOCAL_MODULE := CalcNative
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog
LOCAL_ENABLE_APROF_JNI := true
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

My file explorer screenshot where the aprof file is not reflected
[image: FileExplorer SCREEN]

Please let me know if there is anything wrong in my process or a better way to achieve the results of native code profiling

Comment: Can someone answer this please..